# How to prevent Flexbox from cropping any images

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I want to use Flexbox for an image gallery that will have no cropped images.  I have many, perfectly square photos, and I want to be able to align them on the page, making sure that no image is "cut off" or cropped when resizing the browser.

I would prefer that as many images as can fit to be displayed, but when there isn't an even fit, an image is either bumped down to the next row, or hidden completely.  This way all of the images will maintain their image ratio.

I am using flexbox right now, because I like how easy it makes alignment, and am curious if I could do this with flexbox, but any other suggestions would be great too.

Comment: You could use the flex-wrap property to do this quite easily.

Comment: Thank you but even with flex-wrap, some cropping occurs if the browser window is resized (by scrolling up from the bottom), I am trying to get it so that sort of "overflow hidden" instead hide the entire image

Comment: can you show some code?